watchdog oncreated trigger twice
I am facing problem where watchdog oncreated event trigger twice when a new file is created.
Right now the script is monitoring a folder and when a new file is created or move to this folder it should trigger oncreated once, but it is now trigger twice. However it is very weird that it behave normal for a few days but then suddenly one of the folder got weird. where the file craeted in C folder will trigger twice. I have no idea why this happen.
Before i was monitoring recursively in a root folder, i thought recursively is the reason
monitor_path = r'z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files'
event_handler = MyHandler()

    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, monitor_path, recursive=True)

    try:
        observer.start()
        print(f"Monitoring started on {monitor_path}...")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)  # Keep the script running
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        print("Monitoring stopped.")

    observer.join() 

and so i change the monitoring path into multiple and set recursively to false:
paths_to_monitor = [
        r'z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\SP',
        r'z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\SP1',
        r'z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\HF',
        r'z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\LD'
    ]

    # monitor_path = r'C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\TestFiles'

    observer = Observer()
    event_handler = MyHandler()

    for path in paths_to_monitor:
        logger.info(f"Scheduling monitoring for: {path}")
        observer.schedule(event_handler, path, recursive=False)

    try:
        observer.start()

        print(f"Monitoring started on {monitor_path}...")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)  # Keep the script running
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
        print("Monitoring stopped.")

    observer.join()  # Prevent main program from exiting

But it didnt help.
2024-11-28 16:58:26 - DEBUG    | Event triggered: created, File: z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\SP1\SP1.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:26 - INFO     | File created: SP1.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:38 - DEBUG    | Event triggered: created, File: z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\SP\SP.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:38 - INFO     | File created: SP.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:38 - DEBUG    | Event triggered: created, File: z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\SP\SP.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:38 - INFO     | File created: SP.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:46 - DEBUG    | Event triggered: created, File: z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\HF\HF.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:46 - INFO     | File created: HF.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:56 - DEBUG    | Event triggered: created, File: z:\Testdatabkp\testScript_file\Test_files\LD\LD.CSV
2024-11-28 16:58:56 - INFO     | File created: LD.CSV

My main concern and question is:

It works fine at the beginning and start acting weirdly randomly. why does this happen
why does it happen to one of the folder and not all.

Not sure if its helpful, but all this is running on windows, and the path is a network drive in LAN.
It is bugging me for days, help XC
